# How to up vote more than once to an answer (suggestion for new feature)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Sometimes I asked some questions in `StackOverflow` or even face with some `usefull answers` which I wanted to assign **two or tree up vote** to it.

I know that `there is no ability right now, or even in future` cause it doesn't make sense that a person give 2 or tree upvote to an answer.

Currently I assign a bounty on my (or others) question and mark with this, I assign more than one upvote toan answer.

Isn't it better to **add another feature** which is `only available to questioner` in which `whenever he marked it, the answer took a reputation for it`, it also can assign some `new badges` which whoever took 5, 10, or 20 **`SuperCoolAnswer symbol`** he own these badges.

Answer (score 8):

**No, it's not better.**

We already have that feature, and you've already discovered it. It's called a **bounty**. That's one of the major reasons that it exists, for an asker to award people additional "bonus points" for being particularly helpful in answering one of their questions.

Beyond that, askers already have the *exclusive* ability to accept the answer that they found to be most helpful in solving their problem (in addition to regular upvotes). No one else is, or will ever be, allowed to accept an answer *for* them. That's an additional +15 point "bonus" that they can choose to give to one particular answerer.

Why would we possibly need to add an additional feature that mostly duplicates existing functionality, but call it something entirely different?

Answer (score 3):

> The conception of political equality
>   from the Declaration of Independence,
>   to Lincoln's Gettysburg Address, to
>   the Fifteenth, Seventeenth, and
>   Nineteenth Amendments can mean only
>   one thing — one person, one vote.
>   — Chief Justice Warren, [*Reynolds v. Sims*](http://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/html/historics/USSC_CR_0377_0533_ZO.html) (1964)

Questioners already have a vital tool to reinforce their gratitude to answerers: choosing the best answer. When choosing the best answer, it should be almost reflexive that you hit the upvote button as well. You have now given the answerer 25 points, compared to the 10 points others were able to give him.

Comment: Let me guess... You're not a computer science major? ;-)

Comment: Actually I am. ;)

Comment: Actually, I believe that accepting an answer is implicitly scored as an upvote for it as well. It's 15 points regardless of an explicit upvote.

Comment: Yes, I know. My point was that an upvote is an additional declaration of gratitude, akin to a second vote for the question asker.